# Can I post formatted Source Code on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, code-formatting

I want to create a page on the Facebook, where I want to post Code from different languages.

1. Does Facebook provide any means of posting formatted code on the
   wall?
2. Is there an API for doing so on Facebook?

Comment: You can't post formatted source on a Post

Comment: Facebook AFAIK will let you write anything you want on your facebook page (modulo prohibitions against hate speech, etc.).  Why wouldn't they let you write (formatted) source code?    Whether there is an API for you to automate the posting of stuff on your page is another matter and I don't know the answer.  If I were Facebook, I wouldn't allow it, as it is likely to turn instantly into a source of automated spam.

Comment: @IraBaxter Facebook either strips or interprets both MarkDown and HTML as literal text, so while you can post whatever content you want, you most certainly cannot format it how you want. Although I seen several suggested workarounds, but never tried them myself.

Comment: @Master, there is absolutely not means of posting a private question on SO, or sharing it with anyone but all fellow members, as there is also not such thing as a private group. These ideas a contrary to all that SO was built on and stands for. AFAIK your only option there is some little known forum, or your own blog. The latter is so very easy to achieve, why not give that a go? 

If gather subscribers and regular readers, it is possible with either customization or some add-in, to assign them to private groups, whose members are the only ones granted access to certain pages or post types.

Comment: for q3. now there is SO for teams.

Comment: April 22, 2019 4 spaces and your post should have a grey background that enables the code format. (only works in new posts)

Comment: This works on Stack, not on Facebook

Answer (score 8):

**July 2019 update**

You can do it in two ways, but only in **group posts**.

- using markdown syntax (``` before and after the code snippet)
- using 4 spaces before each line of code

**IMPORTANT**: it only works when you actually type out the backticks or spaces, it doesn't work when you copy and paste the entire post.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work now (November 2020)

Comment: No, it doesnt work

Comment: I've tried this was already working in the past, but now it doesn't work anymore. I wonder why?

Answer (score 6):

Short answers to short, on-point questions:

(Jan 2018)

**1. No**

**2. No**

(Updated Jan 2022)

Comment: Only on Workplace. But you can in Messenger [desktop only]

Answer (score -4):

You can use static html to write your own codes on a facebook page. It will create new tabs where you can write all html, javascript codes as you wish.

Answer (score -5):

Save the code and paste it into your Facebook wall as an image.

Comment: Why should that be a good idea? Any user willing to re-use the code would have to type it from the image